# Get number of weekends between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to get the number of weekends between dates in sql as a function. I have tried but stuck up somewhere in the logic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_NumberOfWeekEnds(@dFrom DATETIME, @dTo   DATETIME)

RETURNS INT AS

BEGIN

   Declare @weekends int

   Set @weekends = 0

   While @dFrom <= @dTo Begin

      If ((datepart(dw, @dFrom) = 1))    

                  Set @weekends = @weekends + 1

                  Set @dFrom = DateAdd(d, 1, @dFrom)

   End

   Return (@weekends)

END
```

Comment: You need to specify what happens when border dates that are overlaping with weekend days. What happens when you specify saturday and sunday, or friday and saturday, or sunday and sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the if statement with this:

```
If ((datepart(dw, @dFrom) = 1) OR (datepart(dw, @dFrom) = 7))
```

You should also check the end of the week to get the result.

Comment: This is dependent on SET DATEFIRST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

I tried out this logic with several edge cases and it seems to work.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @dFrom, @dTo)/7+1
    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,@dFrom) IN (1,7) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,@dTo) IN (1,7) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
```

You can change the CASE statements depending on how you want to handle cases where the start or end date is in a weekend.  In my case I'm not including the weekend if the start or end date is a Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @date_from DATETIME,
@date_to DATETIME


/*TEMPORARY TABLE*/
DECLARE @DATES AS TABLE (
GDate DATETIME
)
SELECT @date_from ='2019-09-10'
SELECT @date_to ='2019-10-10'

/*DATE GENERATED*/
WITH dates
AS (
SELECT @date_from AS dt

UNION ALL

SELECT DATEADD(D, 1, dt)
FROM dates
WHERE dt < @date_to
)

/*INSERTED DATES INTO TEMP TABLE */
INSERT INTO @DATES
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, dt) AS Gdate FROM dates

/*Get Records from temp table*/
SELECT Gdate FROM @DATES
```

Answer (score 1):

Used below logic to calculate the no of Saturdays or Sundays between a start date and end date.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WEEKEND_COUNT
(
@Start_Date datetime,
@End_Date datetime
)
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN
    Declare @count int = 0;
    while @Start_Date<=@End_Date
        Begin
        IF DatePart(WEEKDAY,@Start_Date) =  1 or DatePart(WEEKDAY,@Start_Date) =  7
        SET @count=@count+1
        SET @Start_Date=DateAdd(d,1,@Start_Date)
        END

return @count 
END
```

--Use below to get the count of Saturdays and Sundays

```
Select dbo.WEEKEND_COUNT('Your start date','your end date')
```

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the number of sunday between two dates

```
SELECT DateDiff(ww, @dFrom, @dTo) as NumOfSundays
```

Comment: No this won't Try this SELECT DateDiff(ww, '2015-03-15', '2015-03-20') as NumOfSundays   3/15/2015 is a Sunday, this results in a zero, not a one.